# Python requests error 10060

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests, urllib

I have a script that crawls a website.
Untill today it ran perfect,
However it does not do so now.

it give sme the following error:

```
 Connection Aborted Error(10060 ' A connection attempt failed becvause the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established a connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'
```

I have been looking into answers ans settings but i cannot figure out how to fix this...

In IE i am not using any Proxy (Connection -> Lan Settings-> Proxy = Disabled)

it breaks in this piece of code, somethimes the first run, somethimes the 2nd.. and so on

```
def geturls(functionurl, runtime):
startCrawl = requests.get(functionurl, headers=headers)
mainHtml = BeautifulSoup(startCrawl.content, 'html.parser')
mainItems = mainHtml.find("div",{"id": "js_multiselect_results"})
for tag in mainItems.findAll('a', href=True):
    tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin(url,tag['href'])
    if shorturl in tag['href'] and tag['href'] not in visited:
        if any(x in tag['href'] for x in keepout):
            falseurls.append(tag['href'])
        elif tag['href'] in urls:
            doubleurls.append(tag['href'])
        else:
            urlfile.write(tag['href'] + "\n")
            urls.append(tag['href'])

totalItemsStart = str(mainHtml.find("span",{"id": "sab_header_results_size"}))
if runtime == 1:
    totalnumberofitems[0] = totalItemsStart
    totalnumberofitems[0] = strip_tags(totalnumberofitems[0])
return totalnumberofitems
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Your script is probably being blocked because it's obvious you're a scraper.

Comment: How is this obvious? I request a page once every 5 seconds. And I use headers to make website think I'm a user

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude, sorry. However, all of your requests would be coming from one IP address, every 5 seconds. If someone was watching the server logs or had primitive monitoring software running, you would stand out clearly as an outlier and a scraping bot.

Comment: I didn't think it was rude, just wanted an explanation. However I do need a fix for this! I am in limits of amount of page requests that the website provides (1800 per hour) the only thing I am not doing is complying to their robot.txt

Comment: Find another way to do the scraping that cycles IPs, you could also try using scrapy which has some built in tricks to disguise what you're doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the `timeout` parameter of your `requests.get` method :

```
requests.get(functionurl, headers=headers, timeout=5)
```

But the odds are that your script is being blocked by the server to prevent scrapping attempts . If this is the case you can try faking a web browser by setting appropriate headers .

```
{"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)", "Referer": "http://example.com"}
```

Comment: I haven't got the timeout parameter but I do have the headers, (hence headers=headers). What I don't have is the .net and referer parameter. What does referer do?