# Python-requests [('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060) ]

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using **Python 3.7** with **requests 2.23.0** library and trying to scrape a website, but get the following error message:

`('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))`

I used **agent** but no luck, I also tried to specify the **timeout**, still facing the same problem.

The website works fine when I access it through the browser

I used the same code with some other websites and it just worked fine.

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

-I am able to catch the exception, but I want to avoid it and actually access the website

Here is the code (just as simple as trying to access the website):

```
from requests import get

try:
    agent = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}

    url = "the url I'm trying to access"
    html = get(url, headers = agent)

except (Exception) as error :
    print ("Error", error)
```

Could it be something with the security of the website? I'd like to find a way to workaround

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking for Timeout Error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210792/checking-for-timeout-error-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used selenium with user-agent option and I was able to access the website

`user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))`

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I could not comment due to low reputation,So posting as answer,
I think you will find your answer in below link:

[Python3 error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753345/4511992)

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. now it gives me this msg [HTTPSConnectionPool(host='the website', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)]